# Hashing with linear probing in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

Can anyone explain me, what DeletedNode class is doing what the purpose of `DeletedNode():HashNode(-1, -1){}`.

Please explain the pointer concept here

```
HashNode ** htable = new HashNode*[Tablesize];

const int Tablesize=10;

class HashNode {
public:
    int key;
    int value;
    HashNode(int key, int value) {
        this->key=key;
        this->value=value;
    }
};

class DeletedNode : public HashNode {
private:
    static DeletedNode * entry;
    DeletedNode() : HashNode(-1, -1) {}     // Please explain this
public:
    static DeletedNode * getNode() {
        if (entry == NULL)
            entry = new DeletedNode();
        return entry;
    }
};

DeletedNode * DeletedNode::entry = NULL;    //Why this?

class HashMap {
public:
    HashNode ** htable;
    HashMap() {
        htable = new HashNode*[Tablesize];  // Please explain the pointer concept here
        for (int i = 0; i < Tablesize; i++)
            htable[i] = NULL;
    }

    int HashFunc(int key) { return key % Tablesize; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when you delete an entry from the hash table which is part of a "collision cluster", a contiguous block of elements that happen to have the same hash value.

Let's say elements A, B, and C all hash to the same value `h`. In this case, they will be inserted into the table at positions `h`, `h + 1` and `h + 2`, respectively:

```
--------
A        h
--------
B        h + 1
--------
C        h + 2
--------
```

Now what happens if you delete B? If we do the deletion naively, then there will be a hole between A and C:

```
--------
A        h
--------
         h + 1
--------
C        h + 2
--------
```

Now if you try to look up C in the hash table, its hash value will be `h`, so the search for it will begin at position `h`. However, the next entry at position `h + 1` is now empty, hence **the linear probing search will terminate prematurely,** and you will get the wrong result that C isn't in the table.

In order to prevent the premature termination of the search, a special "dummy" node needs to be inserted in the empty place, which says "there was something here some day which has now been deleted, but I'm part of a collision cluster anyway, so keep searching".

Comment: Thanks, i got this answer. Can you please explain the pointer part for creating the tablesize?

Comment: @DeepPradhan ewww… what?